# Why doesnt required work to validate my forms?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to validate some text-fields using the required keyword, yet nothing is working?

How do I create validation using the required keyword.

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="Name" class="tabcontent">

    <form>
        <div class="nameDiv">
              Title: <input type="text" name="Title" title="Title" id="TitleTransfer">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="addressDiv">
              Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="NameTransfer" required />
            <span class="asterisk"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="emailDiv">
              Surname:
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="LastNameTransfer" required />
            <span class="asterisk"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="numberDiv">
              Email Address:
            <input type="text" name="email Address" id="EmailTransfer" required />
            <span class="asterisk"></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="numberDiv">
              Phone number:
            <input type="text" name="Phone number" id="NumberTransfer">
        </div>
        <button  id="save-btnOne" onclick="moveContentOne()">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the `required` attributes tells the browser that the form field must contain something, this is a weak validation and can be supressed when hooking the form submit through javascript (keep in mind that you do not have delivered any kind of javascript source here that might be in the orbit of the form).

I assume that the `moveContentOne()` hooking the `onclick`-event is the only javascript attached. Considering this the `onSubmit`-event remains untouched and will be also fired alongside of your `onClick` intervention. You should prefer to hook `onSubmit` for forms of that kind to apply custom validation, but that might detach the browser's default behavior for form validation (including the required-attachment to fields).

You might take a look at this guide: [Form data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation)

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
    if (x == "") {
        alert("Name must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

Use this type of validation.
This works for

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="validateForm()">
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
</form>
```

Some browsers do not support required field.
Change the code to your need.
I hope it helps you.

Comment: You should add it to snippet to run  it.